# Find the recent date in a SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server

I need to extract three columns from a table, let's say id, state, date. But the state can be only `FL` AND `CA` values. My issue is that there will be rows that have same id but different state. From those rows I want to keep the row that has the most recent date, regardless of the state value

```
id    state     date
----------------------------
2      FL       02/27/2007
3      CA       09/10/2019
2      CA       08/10/2014
3      FL       04/12/2000
```

OUTPUT

```
2      CA       08/10/2014
3      CA       09/10/2019
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the fast response. something i forgot to mention is that the original table has thousands of rows.thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be looking for something like this ([Using `CTE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15))

```
;with cte as ( -- Step 1: Get Id & The_most_recent_date
  select Id, Max(Date) The_most_recent_date
  from #a
  group by Id
)
select a.* -- Step 2: Join with the original table with the achieved above values 
from #a a
inner join cte on a.Id = cte.Id and a.date = cte.The_most_recent_date
```

**Solution 2 - Using *ROW_NUMBER()***

```
;WITH CTE AS (
  select *,  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Date DESC ) row_num
  from #a 
  where state in ('FL', 'CA') -- Filter to get FL & CA Only
)
Select Id, State,Date
from cte
where row_num = 1
```

[Run online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a09d020effb37b4f1e627453cdd2ec3a)

[image]

Comment: hi. thanks for your help. the original table(A) that i have have thousands of rows and several columns. from A i need to extract id, state= FL and state=CA, and finally the date. but i need the recent date of that id regardless if its FL or CA. thanks so much

Comment: Did you try the second solution? Does this answer your question?

Comment: tried, but is giving me other states that i dont need

Comment: Give me more of your sample data with the corresponding result. Because of my answer based on your post description.

Comment: got it. after row_num=1 i added "and (state='FL' or state='CA')" and it worked. thanks so much for the help